# Unity Make Inspector Look Clean

Tags: unity-game-engine

Recenlty i am to attach 30+ 2D chain all to one object, everything works well but the inspector look kind of messy, is there a way to make it look clean?

I recall seeing something like a Seperate Line in the Component Section of the inspector.

Please kindly provide the name of the seperate line if anyone or other method to tidy up the  Component Section of the inspector.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can make custom inspectors or even editor windows - but thats way beyond the scope of SO - go have a look

Comment: Are you looking for an attribute like [SpaceAttribute](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpaceAttribute.html)?

Comment: Putting floating windows onto another virtual desktop or display and switch between them is not what you are looking for, but it might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Header` attribute before a group of properties.
This makes the inspector look much cleaner with little effort.

```
[Header("Data")]
[SerializeField] private ContentFolder desktopFolder;
[SerializeField] private ContentInfo infoContent;

[Header("Parents")]
[SerializeField] private Transform shortcutsParent;
[SerializeField] private Transform explorerParent;

[Header("Prefabs")]
[SerializeField] private Explorer explorerPrefab;
[SerializeField] private PasswordPrompt passwordPromptPrefab;
[SerializeField] private Explorer installerPrefab;
```

[image: Inspector Sections via Header Attribute]

For more control over rendering or for custom interactions and layout, use a `Custom Editor` (for individual components), `Editor Window` (for tools), and `Property Drawer` (for objects rendered in inspector).